# How to parse a list in python using re

Tags: python, regex, bash

I am trying to parse a list to get the individual images returned by the bash script (stored in the list errors in py script). How can I do this with "re" ?

**bash script**

```
#!/bin/bash
value(){
for entry in *
do
if expr "$(file -b $entry)" : 'JPEG ' >/dev/null; 
then
    echo -e "$entry"
fi  
done
}
value
```

**python code**

```
import subprocess
errors = [subprocess.check_output(['/black.sh'])]
print errors
```

**Output**

```
11_37_24.jpeg
11_38_02.jpeg
11_39_56.jpeg
11_40_20.jpeg
11_40_32.jpeg
11_45_03.jpeg
```

The list `"errors"` is getting assigned a string of length 1:

```
errors = ["11_37_24.jpeg 11_38_02.jpeg 11_39_56.jpeg 11_40_20.jpeg 11_40_32.jpeg 11_45_03.jpeg"]
```

However, I want to get those images separately to use it in an html page. How can I do that with "re"? Is there any other alternative?

Comment: Do you really want re? Wouldn't `errors.split()` suffice?

Comment: Looks like it should be [`errors = subprocess.check_output(['/black.sh']).split()`](https://ideone.com/9x7AyN) unless the file names have spaces in them.

Comment: @StephanW. That would break filenames containing spaces. `errors.split('\n')` is safer. Even better would be to add `\0` at the end of the filenames and use `.split('\0')`.

Comment: @Bakuriu That's what OP wants. Except it should be `errors[0].split()`. Virtually wrapping the `subprocess` call in a list is not a good idea.

Comment: @erip No, it's not what the OP wants. if he has a file named `11 37 24.jpeg` using `.split()` breaks it, while using `.split('\n')` preserves the file name. Note that the bash code is using property quoting.

Comment: @erip You cannot assume that the 5 line example of the OP includes every possible use case of its code. You **should** write code that handles as many cases as possible. Filenames with spaces are common. If the OP code might end up in someone else machine the code should still work for at least the common cases. Not doing so is just dumb. If the Op was completely uninterested in handling whitespace why is he doing `echo "$entry"` instead of `echo $entry`?

Comment: @Bakuriu So then OP could just split on `.jpeg` and concat `.jpeg` to every filename.

Comment: In any case I believe you should just get rid of the bash script and use the [`imghdr`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/imghdr.html) module to check whether a file is a jpeg image or not.

Comment: @erip No, because a user could have `my.jpeg. image.jpeg` as a single filename.

Comment: @Bakuriu While exaggerated, your arguments are fair. What isn't fair is asking why OP made design decision as a defense when the question is about using `re` to split a string. ;) In any case, post the answer if you feel it's a strong one.

Comment: using .split('\n') is doing the job for now. thank you guys !!!

Comment: @Bakuriu: I was also going to suggest using `imghdr`, I even started writing some code, but then I discovered that `imghdr.what` doesn't detect JPEG files that have an ICC_PROFILE embedded before the JFIF marker. :( The `file` utility correctly detects that these are JPEG files.

Comment: Ah, it looks like this is a known bug: [imghdr doesn't recognize variant jpeg formats](https://bugs.python.org/issue16512)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make a few assumptions (based on the example input you give):

- file names only contain digits and underscores (so I can use `\w` in regex)
- words in a file name are always concatenated by underscores (no spaces)
- every file is a jpeg file

The code:

```
import re

errors = ["11_37_24.jpeg 11_38_02.jpeg 11_39_56.jpeg 11_40_20.jpeg 11_40_32.jpeg 11_45_03.jpeg"]

re.findall('\w+\.jpeg', errors[0])
['11_37_24.jpeg', '11_38_02.jpeg', '11_39_56.jpeg', '11_40_20.jpeg', '11_40_32.jpeg', '11_45_03.jpeg']
```

If my assumptions are wrong for your project, `re` is probably not the way to go.

**EDIT**

The OP used the following code (which was given in the comments):

```
errors[0].split('\n')
```

Comment: your assumptions are right and it is working decently. thanks !!